# Windows Phone - Download link instead of store download

Tags: hyperlink, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-store

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 application, since this application is only used intern its unnecessary to upload it to the store. We'd like to share it through a download link instead.

I'd like to know if this is possible for Windows Phone applications since I didn't find anything about it.

Comment: Well, an easy way is to use an MDM, such as Microsoft Intune.

Comment: @Barnstokkr If I do, I don't have to upload it to the store..?

Comment: You don't have to, but in some cases it is easier for certification issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can publish your app with link only download from your "Distribution and visibility" section in dev center. If you select this option than people with only app link can download your app and it will be hidden in the store from global availability.
Please check this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/set-app-pricing-and-availability#dist_vis) documentation for more details.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I found out of it just before u told me. Its working great now.